# Google map customizations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm new to gooogle map developing.i want to make a map as follows.
http://edition.cnn.com/SPECIALS/world/arab-unrest/index.html

But i have no idea how to start this development.Could someone please tell me the way to do this? If you have any worked through examples, that would be a real help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - do you want replace the images for maps? If so, you've got troubles - no one is going to make that, and Google maps are provided as is.

If you simply want to add some layers with animation - try to [read the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays) about overlays.

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't, I recommend you start with Google Maps API Tutorial on http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

Answer (score 0):

i found this link.this is will be helpful for others.

http://www.wolfpil.de/